# Flash as2 EXE changes text size in different pc's

Tags: flash, text, fonts, actionscript-2, exe

I have an EXE file animation that is generated in flash CS6, made with AS2.
This animation has marquee texts dynamically generated.

In my PC I see the text well, but in other PC I'm seeing that font looks smaller.

The font is Verdana and font size is defined by AS2 reading a configuration.xml file

Why the font is changing of size if should be equal in any PC? both with same win OS and Verdana is not a font from other world.

Comment: Maybe on 2nd PC your EXE cannot read xml (different paths, etc) and uses some default value? Also you can embed font in your EXE to avoid potential system font inconsistencies...

Comment: thanks for your response, I'll embed the font, but I wonder why this issue..
the xml is loaded correctly in both pc's